# How to change the Date format in VBA for Outlook?

Tags: vba, date, outlook, format

I am going to build a VBA macro for sending email in Outlook.

```
Sub Today Email()
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Set msg =Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
msg.To = ""
msg.Subject = Date & " Bla Bla Bla"
msg.Body = "Good morning!,<p>Today is & Date:</p>"
msg.Display
 'msg.Attachments.Add ("")
Set msg = Nothing
End Sub
```

the date shows as 15/3/2022. What should I do if I need 15 Mar 2022?

Something like Format(Date) = "dd mmm yyyy" ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications

Comment: `msg.Subject = Format(Date, "dd mmm yyyy") & " Bla Bla Bla"`

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that the date is formatted as Microsoft Outlook expects, use the `Format` function. For example:

```
msg.Subject = Format("1/15/22 3:30pm", "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & " Bla Bla Bla"
```

The [Format function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) returns a Variant (String) containing an expression formatted according to instructions contained in a format expression.